# MVC Razor executing both results of conditional operator?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I have the following code in an MVC 5 Razor view:

```
Welcome <span id="logindd_lblUserName">@(Model.FranchiseFamily == null ? User.Identity.Name : Model.FranchiseFamily.FirstName)</span>
```

When Model.FranchiseFamily is null, I get a null reference exception on this line, so it seems like it's executing both sides of the condition regardless of the result of the expression. I've verified Model and user.Identity.Name are not null. This is not the normal behavior for C#. Is this the expected behavior in a Razor view or have I made a mistake?

Comment: Make no difference that its in a razor code block. Are you sure both `Model` and `user.Identity` are not `null`? And are you sure this is the line that throws the exception? What are the actual details of the exception

Comment: Expand that statement so it's easier to narrow down what is throwing the exception. `@if (Model.FranchiseFamily == null) { ... } else { ... }`

Comment: The details are just System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. at line 36, which is that line. However, it's lying. See my answer below. Thanks for confirmation that it shouldn't matter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is stupid...apologies. After I posted the question, I went and commented out that line so I could continue working. It then showed a null reference on the previous Razor expression several lines higher. I commented that one and it changed to the previous Razor expression. So I removed code until I found the last line of code which was the actual culprit:

```
<input id="logindd_hdnWebName" type="hidden" value="@Model.Franchise.WebName" />
```

I've never seen it report the wrong line number in a view before.